# how to update aws keys in ~/.aws/credentials file for a profile using cli?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-iam, aws-cli

So I am under a security protocol which goes like this

1. local machine is given a user-group to login to aws with basic read only permissions
2. local machine then creates a local ~/.aws/credentials file with multiple profiles in it
3. Now for different project , these local aws profile are allowed to assume the project IAM role with the command
   `aws sts assume-role $PROJECT_IAM_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name $DUMMY_SESSION_NAME --profile $DESIRED_AWS_PROFILE > temp_credentials_file.json`
4. step 3 creates a temporary credentials valid for one hour and writes in the file in a format like

```
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "dummy_aasume_role_id:DUMMY_SESSION_NAME_VALUE", 
        "Arn": "PROJECT_IAM_ROLE_ARN/DUMMY_SESSION_NAME_VALUE"
    }, 
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "dummy_SecretAccessKey", 
        "SessionToken": "dummy_SessionToken", 
        "Expiration": "_some_time_stamp", 
        "AccessKeyId": "dummy_AccessKeyId"
    }
}
```

5. and my credentials file is like

```
[profile_1]
aws_access_key_id = dummy_access_key_id_profile_1
aws_secret_access_key = dummy_aws_secret_access_key_profile_1
region = dummy_region_profile_1
aws_session_token = dummy_aws_session_token_profile_1

[profile_2]
aws_access_key_id = dummy_access_key_id_profile_2
aws_secret_access_key = dummy_aws_secret_access_key_profile_2
region = dummy_region_profile_2
aws_session_token = dummy_aws_session_token_profile_2

[profile_3]
aws_access_key_id = dummy_access_key_id_profile_3
aws_secret_access_key = dummy_aws_secret_access_key_profile_3
region = dummy_region_profile_3
aws_session_token = dummy_aws_session_token_profile_3
```

Now How do I read temp_credentials.json file , and set all 3 aws keys for any given profile in ~/.aws/credentials file via cli without affecting the other files

I have also tried

```
sudo aws configure set AccessKeyId dummy_value --profile profile_2
```

but it didn't work

command goes successfully but content in ~/.aws/credentials file doesn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be something like:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id dummy_access_key_id_profile_1 --profile profile_1
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key dummy_aws_secret_access_key_profile_1  --profile profile_1
```

Names of the variables need to match these, supported by the configuration. In your example `set AccessKeyId` attempts to set an invalid variable. It need to be changed to `set aws_access_key_id`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html